# C# DataGridView combobox add data programmatically

Tags: c#, items, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have an application with a DataGridView. One of the columns is of the type Combobox. I want to add the items for this combobox programmatically. Here is the code I use for that:

```
this.dsStatussen = this.statussenMan.getAllStatussen();
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cd = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.dgvEenheden.Columns[3];
        cd.DataSource = dsStatussen;
        cd.DisplayMember = "statussen";
        cd.DataPropertyName = "sid";
        cd.ValueMember = "status";
```

Then when I try to add a row I get the following error: "There is no field with the name status". I transelated the error to English because I have a Dutch error.
Here is the code I use for adding the rows:

```
Eenheden eenhedenMan = new Eenheden(objEvenement.eid);
        DataSet EenhedenData = eenhedenMan.getAllEenheden();

        foreach (DataRow dr in EenhedenData.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            dgvEenheden.Rows.Add(
                                    dr[0].ToString(), 
                                    dr[1].ToString(), 
                                    dr[2].ToString(), 
                                    Convert.ToInt32(dr[6]), 
                                    dr[3].ToString(), 
                                    dr[4].ToString(), 
                                    dr[5].ToString()
                                );
        }
```

Could someone help me to figure out what I'm doeing wrong? I can't find it. This is the first time I use an DataGridView with comboboxes.

Comment: What is your actualy DataSource looks like? Odes it have two columns (statussen and status)??

Comment: My Datasource is a DataSet with one table. The table has indeed 2 columns: sid and status

Answer (score 1):

in my experience I found everything seemed to work better if you tied it in through a binding scource, then set the

```
bindingScource.dataScource.Rows.Add( 
                                    dr[0].ToString(),  
                                    dr[1].ToString(),  
                                    dr[2].ToString(),  
                                    Convert.ToInt32(dr[6]),  
                                    dr[3].ToString(),  
                                    dr[4].ToString(),  
                                    dr[5].ToString() 
                                );
```

Comment: U mean that I should bind the data directly from the DataSet EenhedenData to the DataGridView? Like this: dgvEenheden.DataSource = EenhedenData.Tables[0];

When I do that I get the same error: There is no field with the name status".

Comment: Okay, I got it working to the part that the statussen are being binded. So in the Combobox I see the items I want. Now I have a nother problem.

In the datarow I'm adding column 6 (dr[6]) has an integer value indicating the ID of the status that should be selected. How can I programatically select the correct item in the combobox when I add the row?

(Sorry for the double comment, but I can't edit the first one)

Comment: Little extra information: The items in the DataGridviewCombobox are text, the column in the datarow (dr[6]) is an integer!

Comment: try Convert.ToInt32(dr[6].ToString())

Answer (score 0):

Select the correct row? you mean select from the dropdown to see the row inside the datagrid?

```
 int index = dropdown.SelectedIndex();

 for(int count = 0; count < dgvEenheden.Rows.Count; count ++)
{
   if (dgvEenheden.Rows[count].Cells["<enter col name here>"].Value.ToString().equals(dropdown.Items[index].Text))
{
    dgvEenheden.Rows[count].Selected = true; //to select the Row
    dgvEenheden.Rows[count].Cells[<Cell Number>].Selected = true; //to select the specific Cell

}
}
```